# Resolve function in states of $stateProvider getting executed twice

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJs version 1.4.5 and angular-ui-router version 0.2.18 in my application. I have noticed that my resolve functions are getting executed twice for a state.

I have tried to use updated angular-ui-router versions upto 0.4.3 also but the issue is not resolved.

My one of the state definitions is as below:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                '': {
                    resolve: {                            
                        usersList: function() {
                            return MainService.getUsers().UsersData.$promise.then(
                                function(response) {
                                    return response;
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    },
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/main/main.html',
                    controller: "MainController"
                }
            }
        })
```

Resolve functions should not be executed twice. It should be executed only once.

I also noticed that we are first checking if the user has access to a page and then redirecting to it. I have created a sample plunkr in which it is shown that resolved function is getting executed twice: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/evuQuRxYwCNwhAPw?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Comment: Sounds like there may be an error in your application resulting in the route being called twice. This can occur if you declare the controller both in the HTML and in the routing setup.

Comment: I checked that the controller is declared only in state definitions. I came across this issue being listed on ui router github repository: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/37. But still I cant find any solution.

Comment: Did you see the linked issues relating to encoding of slash characters in the URL of the state? I'm not sure if it's relevant to your case or  not.

Comment: For one state, i tried removing slash and using only one word in url. Then resolve was getting executed only once. But I need to use slashes in my url. And I used version 0.4.3 also, even then the issue wasn't resolved.

Comment: I see some suggestion it may be fixed Angular 1.6.8, if it won't cause too much trouble to upgrade. I'm  looking at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1645

Comment: I tried updating it to Angular 1.6.8 but other libraries that I am using get incompatible with it. Is there any other way to resolve the issue?

Comment: @seesharper: I found that we are first checking if the user has access to a page and then redirecting to it. I have created a sample plunkr in which it is shown that resolved function is getting executed twice. Can you explain why? http://next.plnkr.co/edit/evuQuRxYwCNwhAPw?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview

Answer (score 0):

The problem here (referring to [your plnkr](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/evuQuRxYwCNwhAPw?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)) is that the default route is route1, so the app goes straight to that when it loads. At the same time you have an asynchronous API call in the run block to check if the user is authorised for route1. Once the promise on that API call is resolved, the app redirects to route1 a second time, giving you the double resolve.

The approach of having route1 be the default route does not make sense if that route requires an authorization that may be missing. I would suggest:

- Having the default state be like a switch that redirects to either route1 or some other route (whatever is seen by an unauthorized user) depending on the authorised state of the user. The redirect logic can be in the switch controller.
- Implementing a handler for '$stateChangeStart' that checks the authorization of the user and redirects them if they aren't authorized (be sure to persist their auth status somewhere of course so you aren't calling that async API every time!)

Comment: In my real application, i have a default landing page to which the user is redirected in case a user is not authorized to access the page. In app.run function, 2 code blocks are used:
1) When the user is reloading the page, the access is checked and then it is redirected to requested page or landing page if user doesn't have permission like in below code 
if(isState1Accessible){$state.go('route1'); }  

2) I have used same logic in '$stateChangeStart' callback function.
Only in reloading a state(not default state), resolve function of state is called twice and not when i switch states.